Практическое применение object slicing C#(Присваивание объекта производного класса переменной базового класса)
На протяжении месяца мучаюсь вопросом о присвоении ссылке базового класса ссылку на класс наследника. К примеру
class Person
{
   public string Name;
}
class Worker:Person
{
   public void Work()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Мало денег,надо работать")
   }
}

Можно объявить объект класса Person и присвоить ему объект класса Worker.
Person Nikita= new Worker();
Функционал у нашего Никиты будет обрезан, и из этого исходит вопрос, для чего это может пригодиться на практике, если мы могли присвоить Никите сразу класс Person и по идее получили бы тоже самое?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Попробуйте уточнить вопрос, разбив его на конкретные аспекты. Как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //«object slicing» как таковой не существует в том виде, как, например, в C++ насколько мне известно

@Dev18 при чем тут вообще C++?

@Dev18 перед тем как задать вопрос я немного пошерстил по этому поводу и нашёл упоминание этой проблемы(в из источников так и называеться) в отношении c#
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing
https://codehumsafar.wordpress.com/2018/02/16/object-slicing-in-c/
не  могу польностью полагаться на эти источники, но упомянул в вопросе для большей ясности

@Nubwer 2k19, спасибо за уточнение и ссылки! Я поняла, почему вы использовали этот термин. В C# сам механизм несколько отличается от того, что происходит в C++, но суть проблемы действительно имеет место быть — когда вы приводите объект наследника к типу базового класса, часть функциональности теряется. Это может сбивать с толку, особенно если вы привыкли к другому языку, где термин "object slicing" более распространён. Важно понимать, что в C# это не называется так официально, но всё же полезно знать о подобных особенностях при работе с объектами и наследованием. Спасибо, за ссылки!

Самый простой случай
...это когда у вас есть множество классов наследовавшие от Person и все они разные. Но они все ещё Person и нужно узнать имя каждого:
class Person
{
    public string Name;
}

class Worker: Person
{
    public void Work()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Мало денег,надо работать");
    }
}

class Student: Person
{
    public void Teach()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Мало знаний,надо учиться");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person Nikita = new Worker();
        Person Vasya = new Student();
        Person[] people = [Nikita, Vasya];
        foreach (Person person in people)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
        }
    }
}

Почему по другому нельзя?
К примеру, если мы создадим экземпляр Person потом мы не сможем использовать его как Worker:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person Nikita = new Person();
        Worker NikitaAsWorker = (Worker) Nikita; // Вот эта конвертация приведет к ошибке
        NikitaAsWorker.Work();
    }
}

А вот так можно:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person Nikita = new Worker();
        Worker NikitaAsWorker = (Worker) Nikita;
        NikitaAsWorker.Work();
    }
}


и всё таки не понимаю до конца, почему я не могу изначально присвоить им класс Person
Person Nikita= new Person(); Person Vasya= new Person();
в обоих вариантах у Никиты и Васи тот же функционал. Потом при надобности можно привести их к нужному типу.

@Nubwer2k19 если объявить Person Nikita= new Person();, то вы не сможете использовать возможности Никиты как Worker-а :)

это понятно, я просто не могу понять почему мы не можем присвоить Никите класс Person, ведь по сути что в первом что во втором варианте будет тот же функционал? или я не понял как работает вся эта тема? :(

@Nubwer2k19 дополнил ответ. Взгляните ещё раз

@Nubwer2k19 представьте, что вы принимаете на работу обычного человека и хотите, чтобы он делал работу программиста. Конечно же будут проблемы. Но если принять на работу программиста и просить делать работу обычного человека, то он без проблем сделает. Тут почти тоже самое.

@Nubwer2k19 Потом при надобности можно привести их к нужному типу. - Вот именно что нельзя.

Присвоение объекта производнго класса переменной базового класса — это ключевая возможность, которую предоставляет полиморфизм в C#. Когда вы создаете переменную базового класса и присваиваете ей объект производного класса, вы получаете возможность рабтать с объектами через общий интерфейс базвого класса
Это особенно полезно, когда нужно обрабатывать коллекцию различных объектов, у которых есть общие свойства, но разные реализации методов.
Person Nikita = new Worker { Name = "Nikita" };
Person Vasya = new Student { Name = "Vasya" };
Person[] people = { Nikita, Vasya };

foreach (Person person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}

Здесь все объекты хранятся как тип Person, но на самом деле они могут быть любыми производными от Person классами. Это упрощает управление объектами и кодирование. Если вам необходимо вызвать метод, специфичный для производного класса, вы можете использовать приведение типов:
Worker worker = Nikita as Worker;
worker?.Work();

Таким образом, функционал не теряется, а управление становится гибче.
В случае с object slicing в C++ происходит копирование только базвой части объекта, тогда как в C# это не актуально, так как переменные класса хранят ссылки на объекты. Поэтому вам не нужно беспокоиться о том, что функционал будет "обрезан"

Если мы говорим про c# и .NET, то Microsoft - это наше всё, но в разделе про полиморфизм, на который дана ссылка в ответе, написана явная ерунда: "Еще одну возможность определения метода или набора методов, реализация которых оставлена производным классам, дает интерфейс", потому что интерфейс никакого отношения к наследованию не имеет.

Интерфейсы в C# не являются наследованием в привычном смысле, как у классов. Но все же они ведь играют важную роль в полиморфизме, задавая набор методов, которые должны реализовать классы //нам показывали на примере животных во время учебы `public interface IAnimal
{
void MakeSound();
}
public class Dog : IAnimal
{
public void MakeSound()
{
Console.WriteLine("Bark");
}
}
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
public void MakeSound()
{
Console.WriteLine("Meow");
}
}`

@rotabor интерфейс к наследованию и правда отношения не имеет, а вот к полиморфизму имеет, самое прямое.
